# Rollup failed to resolve import "react-media-recorder" from "/vercel/path0/src/App.jsx"

Tags: reactjs, vite, package.json, vercel, yarn-lock.json

I am trying to deploy my react-app by using Vercel but getting the following error message. I did yarn run build before the deployment and didn't get any errors.

error during build:

> Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "react-media-recorder" from "/vercel/path0/src/App.jsx".
> This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
> If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
> `build.rollupOptions.external`
> at viteWarn (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-
> info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
> Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1

When I test the app everything works fine on the localhost. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend-interview-bot",
  "private": false,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext js,jsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.2.5",
    "antd": "^5.8.4",
    "axios": "^1.5.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.2.15",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.7",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react": "^4.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.45.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-refresh": "^0.4.3",
    "vite": "^4.4.5"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should add react-media-recorder in dependencies list. try this command: npm i react-media-recorder